# Are SNMP MIB's and OID's platform independent?

Tags: snmp, mib, oid

For example, OID for CPU load for 1 minute is .1.3.6.1.4.1.2021.10.1.3.1 in Linux and Cisco router. But I'm not sure if it is just a coincidence or it is secured over various network devices. I haven't found any document which tells that OID's are defined globally, while I've found some platform-specific OID references. I guess it is, but I need a reliable source to convince myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The .1.3.6 MIB tree is generic except for vendor-specific MIB .1.3.6.1.4.1, not all parts of the MIB tree will be implemented by or necessarily relevant to all devices.  The most common subtree is MIB-II which is anything beneath .1.3.6.1.2 or therabouts.  Your OID is part of vendor-specific with vendor 2021 which seems to be some sort of host MIB.